# Efficient PHP object assignment from $_POST

Tags: php

I'm relatively new to PHP. I've created a validation class for user input and looking to see if there is a more efficient way of assigning $_POST variables to it, so at the moment I have:

```
    if (isset($_POST['title']))     $valInput->title=$_POST['title'];
    if (isset($_POST['firstName'])) $valInput->firstName=$_POST['firstName'];
```

Which is working fine but I have nearly 15 variables, so this approach seems a little verbose in terms of code? I know I could use a foreach on the $_POST variables but this is obviously less secure.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can use extract($_POST) to create auto variables, (in case if you don't have any file uploading field in your form). if you use extract, you can call directly the variable $title for getting value of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a loop, something like this:

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    // Instead of blindly adding anything that was posted we make sure a property exists 
    // in $valInput that matches the name of the posted value.
    if (property_exists($valInput, $key))
    {
        $valInput->$key = $val;
    }
}
```

It's still secure because you check that a property of the same name as the posted variable already exists in `$valInput`. This means anything that isn't defined in `$valInput` will be skipped.

If you only want then to be able to edit some properties and not others then you could use public and private declarations to determine which are accessible from outside of the class.

If this still isn't enough, i.e. you want some accessible from outside but not editable then you can use an array to store a whitelist of variables that are editable e.g.:

```
$whitelist = array('foo', 'bar');
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    if (property_exists($valInput, $key) && in_array($key, $whitelist))
    {
        $valInput->$key = $val;
    }
}
```

Or a better option would be to use getters and setters and only create setters for those which you want accessible.

```
class fooBar {
    private $foo;
    private $bar;

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }

    /**
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function getBar()
    {
        return $this->bar;
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $bar
     */
    public function setBar($bar)
    {
        $this->bar = $bar;
    }

}
```

This way people can access both `foo` and `bar` but can only set `bar`. Then you change the foreach to

```
foreach($_POST as $key => $val)
{
    // We add set to the name as we're checking for a set method
    $key = 'set'.ucfirst($key);
    if (method_exists($valInput, $key))
    {
        $valInput->$key($val);
    }
}
```

Comment: I thought about this but isn't this a security risk in that you are allowing any property in the whole object to be modified whereas at least above we are only allowing the specific properties to be set?

Comment: @JAMMac Not really, people would have to know the name of the property before they could change it. If they have that info you've probably got bigger issues. However if you are that concerned about it then you can use getters and setters. I've edited my answer to include this,

Comment: Thank you for a very comprehensive answer.

Comment: @JAMMac your welcome, if this solved your problem please mark the answer as correct.

Answer (score 0):

check this

```
$exclude = array('submit', 'lastname'); // fields to exclude from $_POST array

$valInput = new stdClass(); // empty object

foreach ($exclude as $val) {
    unset($_POST[$val]); // remove unnecessary fields 
}

foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
    $valInput->$key = $val; // assign value to object
}
```

And if you want to select specific fields, try

```
$include = array('title', 'firstname'); // fields to include from $_POST array

$valInput = new stdClass(); // empty object

foreach ($include as $key => $val) {
    if (isset($_POST[$val])) {
        $valInput->$val = $_POST[$val]; // assign value to object
    }
}
```

Comment: I treat $_POST as immutable.  But each to their own.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the object properties and check if the corresponding key exists in the POST array:

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public $foo;
    public $bar;
    public $baz;
    private $bat;
}

$array = array('foo' => 'big', 'bar' => 'fat', 'baz' => 'momma', 'bat' => 'man');

$foo = new Foo;
foreach($foo as $key => $val) {
    if(isset($array[$key])) $foo->$key = $array[$key];
}

var_dump($foo);
```

Outputs:

```
object(Foo)[1]
  public 'foo' => string 'big' (length=3)
  public 'bar' => string 'fat' (length=3)
  public 'baz' => string 'momma' (length=5)
  private 'bat' => null
```